# MySQL query returned 0 rows

Tags: mysql, database

I have a task to make a database only in MySQL. I made 11 tables and connected them via foreign keys. I tried to make a simple query in order to return name and lastname of the patient in his diagnose, but I always get only a header with the first and last name and analysis.

- The patient's table has nameID, name, last name, ID serial number, date of birth and so on, but I wanted only name and last name for the test query.
- The second table I joined is analysis, which has analysisID, patientID, doctorID, hospitalID, diagnosis and so on.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT pat.name, pat.lastname 
FROM patient pat
JOIN analysis a ON pat.patientID = a.patientID 
group by a.analysisID
order by pat.lastname
```

This query returns 0 rows. Please help, I am new at mySQL. I read a lot of tutorials, read posts here about this problem and I still didn't find a solution.

Comment: Could you please show us whatś the data you have on each table (or a sample so we can understand what is happening)?

Comment: The thing that's making me suspicious is the "group by a.analysisID" part, what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to eliminate any duplicate analysisID's for the same person with the use of group by.  If so, you could use the following:

```
Select a.analysisID, pat.name, pat.lastname
from patient pat, analysis a
where pat.patientID = a.patientID
group by a.analysisID, pat.name, pat.lastname
```

What the above query will do is return only one record when the analysisID, name and lastname are all the same.

Comment: I didn't have to put last two columns, as that serves only for aranging the table and didn't impact the result. I made a demo database with only two tables, made a foreign key in a table "patient" for column analysisID and connected it to the table "analysis". 
    Somehow it worked, and I don't have an answer what is wrong with my database. I couldn't just screenshot the tables of my original database because the names are not in english. 
Here are screenshots of my demo database: 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/QXwOZqw)

Comment: I don't think you would want analysisID in the patient table because you would have to enter multiple rows if the same patient had more than one condition.  Use the patient table for patient info only and link to the analysis table by the patientID (like you did above).  For example, you could query all the patients that have had a broken leg by doing a where pat.patientID = a.patientID and a.analysisID=2